# Unknown provider: $q in an AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong. I have this code:

```
var app = angular.module('app',
[
    'angular-cache',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap'  
])

app.config([
    '$httpProvider',
    '$q',
    ($httpProvider,
        $q) => {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(
        function () {
            return {
                'request': function (config) {
                    return config;
                },
                // optional method
                'requestError': function (rejection) {
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                },
                // optional method
                'response': function (response) {
                    return response;
                },
                // optional method
                'responseError': function (rejection) {
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            }
        })
}])
```

When it runs I am getting the message:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app
>   due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $q
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24q
>       at http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:68:12
>       at http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:4397:19
>       at getService (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:4550:39)
>       at injectionArgs (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:4574:58)
>       at Object.invoke (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:4596:18)
>       at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:4497:35)
>       at http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:4506:11
>       at forEach (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:321:20)
>       at loadModules (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:4487:5)
>       at createInjector (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:4409:19)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1828%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4409%3A19)

When I comment out all this code and run my application it works and I don't get this error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject service into config block. However you can use factory service of function as the interceptor. There is already factory example, so I will provider another function solution:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider) => {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                return config;
            },
            // optional method
            'requestError': function(rejection) {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },
            // optional method
            'response': function(response) {
                return response;
            },
            // optional method
            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    }])
}])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only inject providers into a config block, as it runs before any services have been loaded. `$q` is a service, so it's not defined when that block of code runs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject `$q` as a provider. Instead, define your interceptor in a factory then push it to `$httpProvider.interceptors` within `config`. Observe the following...

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('testInterceptor');
}]);
```

---

```
.factory('testInterceptor', ['$q', function($q) {

    return {
        'request': function (config) {
             return config;
         },
         'requestError': function (rejection) {
             return $q.reject(rejection);
         },
         'response': function (response) {
             return response;
         },
         'responseError': function (rejection) {
              return $q.reject(rejection);
         }
    }
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/h3ybxmus/) - demo